# Calculating the horizontal drift for parachute, is it okay to assume the "starting speed" to be terminal velocity?

Tags: parachute, payload

Plus in the worst case of the maximum range, can we assume we are already at the terminal velocity when we're deployed at 600m?

If we assume that we are deployed at 600m, we "freefall" for a few seconds while the parachute completely opens, catches air and reaches terminal velocity.

So then its just a case of balancing the total drag (from both components - falling and sidewind) with the estimated mass of the payload?

Comment: Unless dropping from a stationary delivery platform, your package will have a significant horizontal velocity, you must account for this, both in drift and chute opening time.

Comment: The payload is basically a bomb until the canopy is fully open, following a ballistic trajectory, except that the it's accelerating then decelerating during the deployment, so that has to be accounted for.  If the drop height is several thousand feet, it might be insignificant enough to ignore or just add a ball park fudge factor, but if the drop is very low and you need extreme precision, it can be a quarter of the total estimate.

Comment: Paratroopers who jump with a static line out of a C-17 or C-130 are essentially **at** terminal velocity as soon as they're out of the aircraft. Those who jump from a Blackhawk (or  B.A.S.E. jumper), not so -  they are accelerating _toward_ terminal velocity at the point that their chute starts to deploy. Different cases, different assumptions.

Comment: Also, to be clear on terminology, "terminal velocity" of the jumper/object without parachute is far higher than the terminal velocity **with** parachute. Jumping from a fast aircraft, you may start out near/at/above both of these speeds; the BASE jumper probably never reaches the former, and slows to the latter in less time than his jet-jumping compadre.